# How can I align 4 photos side by side, and their individual text under them?

Tags: html, css, html5shiv

I am trying to create a basic online store type of layout. Just very basic beginners CSS and HTML

Comment: Use CSS flex, css tricks has a nice explanation

Comment: you mean, you don't even know how to type the html and you asking us to free task for us?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do that using flex styling. [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great source for learning flex box (it's what I go to whenever I forget something).

```css
#container{
   display: flex; /*specifies that the items in the container should abide by flex styling*/
   flex-direction: row; /*aligns the items in the container in a row*/
}

.imgContainer{
   text-align: center;  /*aligns the text in the center*/
   padding: 2%; /*adds some extra white space around images*/
}
```

```html
<!-- container element for all of the content. 
It will line up the imgContainers in a row-->
<div id="container"> 
  <!--imgContainers will contain each img and text combination -->
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4">
    <p>This is an image</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4">
    <p>This is an image</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4">
    <p>This is an image</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4">
    <p>This is an image</p>
  </div>
</div>
```